# PHP How to determine if a word is between two open quotes in a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this function to determine if a word is between single/double quotes but it gives a false positive if the word is between two closed quotes.

```
function keyword_in_quotes( $str, $word ) {
    echo $str . "\n";
    if (preg_match('/["\'].*\b' . $word . '\b.*["\']/m', $str))
            echo $word . " found in quotes.\n";
    else
            echo $word . " NOT found in quotes.\n";
}

// this call correctly reports KEYWORD is between quotes
keyword_in_quotes( "Sentence with a 'Specific KEYWORD and other words' in quotes", "KEYWORD" );

// this call incorrectly reports KEYWORD is between quotes
keyword_in_quotes( "Sentence with a 'lead quote' and KEYWORD not in 'quotes' or 'even this'", "KEYWORD" );
```

Which gives the results:

```
Sentence with a 'Specific KEYWORD and other words' in quotes
KEYWORD found in quotes.
Sentence with a 'lead quote' and KEYWORD not in 'quotes' or 'even this'
KEYWORD found in quotes.
```

I'm a bit out of my depth. How can I determine if the given word is only between OPEN quotes? (No limit on number of quotes in the string).

Comment: can quotes be nested `'"like " this'` ?

Comment: Why use regex?  Count the number of single/double quotes leading up to your keyword.  If that number is odd then you're inside of quotes.  Just make sure that you remove quotes embedded in words (i.e. contractions like `can't`) before searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex instead to determine if `KEYWORD` is not in quotes:

```
'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|KEYWORD
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jY9jR3/2)